# python dynamically changing super

Tags: python

I have a couple of classes and for testing I need to replicate these classes with small modifications. Initially, I was just changing a test class to the class it is supposed to mimic after doing the necessary modifications.

```
class Class_A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        do_class_A_stuff


class Class_B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        do_class_B_stuff

....

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, classToMimic):
        doStuffForTest
        self.__class__ = classToMimic
```

which worked fine. However, now I got to the point that I need to run some test method in between do_classX_stuff. So, I can not run the test specific procedure before I change the class, but also after the **init** of the super. My thought was just to dynamically inherit Test and overwrite some methods to add the testing code where necessary.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, classToMimic):
        self..__bases__ = classToMimic   

    def methodToOverwrite(self):
        doStuffForTest
```

Is this a good approach and if so, how can I do that or is there a better solution?

Edit: I had this quite wrong, as Marijn pointed out, I am looking for .**bases**, not **super**. changed in the above and goggling this, I found a little bit more information.

Comment: "Is this a good approach" ... What you are doing *scares* me. So no...

Comment: What on earth is making you do this?

Comment: I'm still not sure that I understand what you're doing well enough to be scared.  Perhaps if you provided some simple code which would actually run to demonstrate the problem...  FWIW, I suspect that the best solution is to use some sort of mocking framework ...

Comment: And, I'm completely not sure what this has to do with `super` ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm also not sure what `__super__` is, or does. I know what `super` is.

Comment: `super()` is a function to produce a special object that'll work with your class inheritance structure to find attributes higher up that structure, for example when you've overridden those attributes. What you are trying to do is dynamically set the *bases* of your class.

Comment: Swapping out the `__class__` attribute may work, but is *rarely* the right thing to do. You can generate a *new* class object with dynamic bases, but this all really smells like a X-Y problem to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a factory to create subclasses:

```
def test(classToMimic):

    class Test(classToMimic):

        def methodToOverwrite(self):
            doStuffForTest

    return Test
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, I guess this was to straightforward for me to come up with it. Looks cleaner than my convoluted path